# three empty lines in the begin of html page

Tags: php

i have html code inside a php variable

```
<?
$HTML_CODE='
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>'.$pg->pgTitle.'</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$cssFile.'" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div id="header">
';

echo $HTML_CODE;
?>
```

When i view the source of my page by in browser ( right click-> view source )

The code starts in line 4

```
1.
2.
3.
4.<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
5.<html>
6.<head>
7.<title>page title</title>
8.<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
9.</head>
10.<div id="header">
```

i've used trim function, it's now start in line 3!!

Comment: What's your question? And why is this a problem?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an issue; no errors will result, but at least one of those lines is due to your code:

```
$HTML_CODE='
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ...
```

this introduces a line feed in.  Additionally, I expect you have some whitespace before your php opening tag `<?`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<? $HTML_CODE='<!DOCTYPE
```

with out the line breaks in your code, also try removing the linebreak between

```
'; and echo
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unnecessary page breaks from your initialisation of variable

```
$HTML_CODE='<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>'.$pg->pgTitle.'</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$cssFile.'" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div id="header">';
```